# Code is not writing to subdirectories as expected and Memory use is high

Tags: xml, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have several xml files in some subdirectories. I wrote a code that converts the parsed xml files to pandasDF and then writes its csv (to the subdirectories their xml data was read from). However, I am getting output csv file in the first subfolder only. How to save my parsed xml files, is there a better way than writing csv? My long term plan is to write to hdf5. Memory use is also very high (checked ram usage), I haven't done any kind of memory/speed optimization before,  if you're feeling generous tips in that direction are appreciated.

```
import xmltodict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import os
import glob
import re

#from list of directories, iterate through each directory and apply my functions    
def change_dir (directories):
    for i in directories:
        os.chdir(i)  
        return parse_xml (i)

#Read xml files from each subdir,parse and append to a list            
def parse_xml (subdirectory):
    doc = []
    for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(subdirectory, '*.xml')):
        with open(i, 'r') as fd:
            doc.append(xmltodict.parse(fd.read()))
    return make_pandas(doc)

#Take list of each subdir xml files, create required df and write csv to subdir
def make_pandas (list_parsedFiles):
    logData_list = []
    for xmlval in list_parsedFiles:
        channel_list = xmlval['logs']['log']['logData']['mnemonicList'].split(",")
        temp = [i.split(",") for i in xmlval ['logs']['log']['logData']['data']]
        temp.insert(0, xmlval ['logs']['log']['logData']['unitList'].split(","))
        logData_list.extend(temp)
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(logData_list).reshape(len(logData_list),len(channel_list)), columns = channel_list).drop_duplicates()
        df.to_csv('out.csv')

%%capture
tocsv = change_dir (list_smallLogs)
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example XML input file that works with this code?

Comment: Do note you can directly convert XML to CSV. Pandas/numpy can be kept for data science needs!

Comment: @Parfait: Surely not "directly," because many XML documents have no obvious translation to CSV at all.

Comment: Well, yes some type of coding is needed such as general use Python between the two types.

Comment: @JohnZwinck is the xml file required? I am happy with the way it is being parsed. I was able to make pandas and write to csv for 1 subdir. My trouble is in navigating and writing in each subdir. Is that why I was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is broken because you `chdir()` to each directory, then `glob(directory)`, which means you are looking for files in `foo/foo`, `bar/bar`, etc.  Don't do the `chdir()` - that's bad practice, you should just specify the path in each function call (as you have already done).

Comment: I get it. I had first written all file paths to a txt/log file and wanted to use that to read data directly. But I found chdir() soln so I tried to use that. See here, please -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680212/read-file-paths-from-log-file-and-perform-function-in-subdirectories

Comment: Don't use `chdir()`.  It is the source of your problems.